# androidのactivity_mainでEditTextにonClickを設定するとエラーが起きる

Tags: android, java, android-layout

androidのactivity_mainでEditTextにonClickを設定するとエラーが起きます。
コードは以下のようになっていて、onClickのコードを消すとエラーが起こりません。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
            android:onClick="clearUrl"
            android:id="@+id/urlText"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showWebsite"
            android:text="Browse"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_weight="1"></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: エラーとありますが、どんなエラーがでますか？

Comment: 実機でテストした時にEditTextをタップすると、「問題が発生したため、Appを終了します。」と表示され、終了してしまいます。

Comment: 終了したときのLogcatは確認しましたか？

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method clearUrl(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'urlText'

Comment: このような、エラーが出現しています。

Comment: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
上記を下記にした所、エラーはなくなりましたが、他のところにエラー(Error:(39, 17) エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
シンボル: メソッド getSupportActionBar())が出てしまいます。
public class MainActivity extends Activity

Answer (score 2):

こちらと同じ事象でしょうか。
[Android EditText onClick Listener defined in Layout fails with obscure Exception - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477364/)

v22.1.0以降(上記URL先記述によると 22.1.0, 22.1.1, 22.2.0 で発生を確認)サポートライブラリのバグのようです。

該当箇所が少ないのであれば、XMLベースのハンドラ設定を行わないように修正する、という暫定対処策が考えられます。

修正箇所が大量にあるのであれば、問題の発生しない古いバージョン(22.0.0)を使用する、というのも暫定対処として一考の余地があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

ActivityにclearUrl(View)とのメソッドが見つからないようですが、clearUrlメソッドは定義されていますか？

Comment: ActivityMain.javaに
    public void clearUrl(View view){
        urlText.setText("");
    }
このように定義しています。

Comment: ほとんど同じ構成でプロジェクトを組んで見ましたが、clearUrlは実行されました。
新しいプロジェクトを作成して同じ構成でやってみると、その差異で何かヒントが見つかるかもしれませんね。
レイアウトコードしかないので憶測ですが、、、
とりあえず同じレイアウトコードで問題なく動いた事だけ、報告します。